# Flutter sqflite does not work on real android device

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I have created an app using sqflite and test it using my own device via usb debugging but when i built it using `flutter build apk` and insatlled it it does not work as in it does not store my notes display it etc .Anyone know a fix?

I tried shrinkResources false proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

after that create file in android/app/proguard-rules.pro add this code

-keep class io.flutter.plugin.editing.** { *; }

I just want it to do the normal operations as it was doing when connected to a usb to my laptop

Answer (score 0):

Did you check logs? I think you can set log in OnCreate method of database and check the functionality in logcat tab (in android studio).